# React.js and Firebase auth: setTimeout Callback function not executed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-authentication, callback, settimeout

I have a function `handleSubmit` that handles registering in Firebase in a react component. Inside, I want to handle errors with my `setErrorTimeout` function, which has a setTimeout that resets the error automatically after 3 seconds in this case..

The problem is, my Timeout is not executed, e.g the callback function inside the timeout is not being executed after 3 seconds, but everything else is.. why?

```
    const handleSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault()

    console.log(formDetails)
 
    if (formDetails.password !== formDetails.passwordrepeat) {
        setErrorTimeout(setRegisterError, {
            message: 'Passwords do not match!',
        })
        return
    }

    console.log('Try')
    console.log(formDetails.email, formDetails.password)
    try {
        auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
            formDetails.email,
            formDetails.password
        )
            .then(userCredentials => {
                if (userCredentials) {
                    const user = userCredentials.user
                    let success = user.sendEmailVerification()
                    console.log('success register:', success)
                    setRegisterSuccess(
                        'You registered successfully! please check your email!'
                    )

                    setFormDetails({})
                }
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log('ERROR!')
                setErrorTimeout(error)
            })
    } catch (e) {
        setErrorTimeout(e)
    }
}


const setErrorTimeout = error => {
    console.log('inside timeout!')
    setRegisterError(error)
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('inside cb!')
        setRegisterError(null)
    }, 3000)
    clearTimeout(timer)
    console.log('after timeout!')
}
```

Comment: I agree with @Frank here. You need to clear the timeout inside the callback of setTimeout. When you call setTimeout, the callback is executed async and the line of code after setTimeout is executed immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're clearing the timeout right after you create it here:

```
const timer = setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('inside cb!')
    setRegisterError(null)
}, 3000)
clearTimeout(timer)
```

You probably want that `clearTimeout` call to be inside the callback, although it's not even strictly needed since the timeout already fired.